# Asp.Net MVC 5 GetAllUsers except Admin Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am building an application using MVC5 where I need to GetAll Users who have a role of either **Client** Or User but not **Admin**.

I am unable to get users who are not associated with admin role.

I also did some tweaks in Identity 2 to use INT Id rather than GUID.

My current query is something like this

This query gives me null Users

```
 var users = _roleManager.FindByName("Admin").Users.Select(e=>e).ToList();
```

while this query gives me all users. But I need to remove admin role users

```
 var users = _context.Users.Select(e => e).ToList();
```

How to get user without admin role?

Comment: I'm not next to my IDE but try something like `var users = _context.Users.Where(u => !u.UserRoles.Contains("Admin")).ToList();`

Answer (score -4):

Try the following query see if it helps :

var users = _context.Users.Where(user => user.Role != "Admin");

Comment: this will only get one user